# Matplotlib giving no error but not plotting anything

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

so this a section of my code, it runs and opens a graph but there is no plot points

```
fig =plt.figure(1)
data= [1.3,2.4]
for i in range(0,2):
    emittx=data[i];
    turns = 1+i;
    plt.plot(turns,emittx,'-r')
plt.show()
```

stuck because I cant really understand why

Comment: Can you give an example which is runnable? That is, containing `data1`? And I assume `plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Comment: why do you have `plot(...)` in a loop? I think you should be constructing lists/arrays of your x and y points and calling `plot` once.

Comment: what I really need to do I think is to get emittx and turns as arrays, emittx comes from a large data set but i only want to read the 12th column and turns to count from 1-len(data1) and then plot them.. is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: three_pineapples: ye thats exactly what I want to do. I seem to be struggling with it, but ive only just started using python today

Comment: Welcome to SO, sorry you got a rather unfriendly welcome.  The problem is that you are plotting a single point using a line style with out markers.  Change to `plot(turns, emittx, 'or')` and you will get markers.

Comment: Annoyingly all of the users who voted to close have no or minimal rep in `python` or `matplotlib`.  There _is_ enough information here for this to be a valid question.  It would be _better_ to include some fake-data to plot instead of trying to plot your actual data.

Comment: I figured the problem out, I took the plotting routine out of the loop (it wasnt supposed to be in there anyway) and wrote emittx and turns as an array and it plotted fine :)

Comment: @mcrouch Please answer your own question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, the problem is because **you are repeatedly (for loop) plotting a SINGLE point** and asking matplotlib to use a line ('-') to connect the single point.

Either plot an array of two or more points (e.g. [2.3, 4.4]) or use markers to represent the data ('o').  For example:

```
fig =plt.figure(1)
data = [1.3,2.4]
for i in range(0,2):
    emittx=data[i];
    turns = 1+i;
    plt.plot(turns,emittx,'or', markersize=10)
plt.show()
```

should allow you to plot single points.